alert dialog shadcn radix ui and async task
I have the following component, and it  has alert dialog inside and async task.
I want the alert dialog to close only after async task has been done, or what is the best practice behaviour?
the alert dialog is triggered from a table from which you need to decline/accepet something (and then router.refresh() for triggering new fetch data for the table)
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "sonner";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

import {
  AlertDialog,
  AlertDialogAction,
  AlertDialogCancel,
  AlertDialogContent,
  AlertDialogDescription,
  AlertDialogFooter,
  AlertDialogHeader,
  AlertDialogTitle,
  AlertDialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/alert-dialog";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { makeServerRequestFromClient } from "@/shared/lib/api";

const ApproveDeclineMeeting = (meetingId: string) => {
  const [isApproved, setIsApproved] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const status = isApproved ? "Active" : "Not approved";
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleAction = (approveValue: boolean) => {
    setIsApproved(approveValue);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const URI = `meeting/${meetingId}`;
      const body = { status: status };
      const method = "PUT";
      const res = await makeServerRequestFromClient({ URI, body, method });
      if (res.ok) {
        toast.success("");
      }
      router.refresh();
    } catch (err) {
      setOpen(true);
      toast.error("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        variant="destructive"
        onClick={() => handleAction(true)}
        className="bg-green2 hover:bg-green2/80"
      >
        Approve
      </Button>
      <Button
        variant="destructive"
        className="mr-2"
        onClick={() => handleAction(false)}
      >
        Decline
      </Button>
      <AlertDialog
        open={open}
        onOpenChange={() => setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen)}
      >
        <AlertDialogTrigger asChild></AlertDialogTrigger>
        <AlertDialogContent>
          <AlertDialogHeader>
            <AlertDialogTitle>Are you absolutely sure?</AlertDialogTitle>
            <AlertDialogDescription>
              This action cannot be undone. This will permanently delete your
              account and remove your data from our servers.
            </AlertDialogDescription>
          </AlertDialogHeader>
          <AlertDialogFooter>
            <AlertDialogCancel>Cancel</AlertDialogCancel>
            <AlertDialogAction onClick={onSubmit}>Continue</AlertDialogAction>
          </AlertDialogFooter>
        </AlertDialogContent>
      </AlertDialog>
    </>
  );
};

export default ApproveDeclineMeeting;

